# count number if times a column has a certain value

Tags: mysql

I have a  table with an id column (same id repeated across rows) and columns `h1` to `h18` where each column could contain either the word `blob`, `par` or `birdie`.

I want to count the number of times the word `blob`, `par` or `birdie` appears in columns `h1` to `h18` and for each `id`.

I want to end up with a table like ...

```
id blob par birdie
-- ---- --- ------
1  5    10  3
2  2    15  1
3  8    8   2
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you should probably [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema somewhat, but as things stand:

```
SELECT id,
       (h1='blob'  )+(h2='blob'  )+...+(h18='blob'  ) AS blob,
       (h1='par'   )+(h2='par'   )+...+(h18='par'   ) AS par,
       (h1='birdie')+(h2='birdie')+...+(h18='birdie') AS birdie
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: My cut down statement is as follows but the oder is not correct ... SELECT p.name, sum((c.h1hs="Blob")+(c.h2hs="Blob")+(c.h3hs="Blob")+(c.h4hs="Blob")+(c.h5hs="Blob")+(c.h6hs="Blob")+(c.h7hs="Blob")+(c.h8hs="Blob")+(c.h9hs="Blob")+(c.h10hs="Blob")+(c.h11hs="Blob")+(c.h12hs="Blob")+(c.h13hs="Blob")+(c.h14hs="Blob")+(c.h15hs="Blob")+(c.h16hs="Blob")+(c.h17hs="Blob")+(c.h18hs="Blob")) as "Blob" FROM player as p, card as c WHERE p.pid=c.pid GROUP BY c.pid ORDER BY "Blob"

Comment: @user1753622: If you want to quote SQL identifiers, use backticks: `\`Blob\``.  Double quotes indicate a string literal, which is constant for every record and therefore has no effect on ordering.

Comment: LOL. I saw that after so changed the name and it worked! Thanks for your answer :o)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also consider this:

```
select
  id,
  sum(word='blob') as blob,
  sum(word='par') as par,
  sum(word='birdie') as birdie
from
  (select id, h1 word from words union all
   select id, h2 from words union all
   select id, h3 from words union all
   ...) w
group by id
```

to make the query faster, you could also write the subquery like this:

```
(select id, h1 word from words where h1 in ('blob', 'par', 'birdie') union all
 select id, h2 from words where h2 in ('blob', 'par', 'birdie') union all
 ...)
```

but it then becomes a little ugly. I would suggest you to normalize your database.